# How can I sort by a value of a "nested" Hash in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My current documents have a similar structure to:

```
{
  'name': 'Sum Guy',
  'age': 31,
  'scores': {'blue': 5, 'yellow': 9, 'red': 2}
}
```

I can't seem to find a proper mapping or way to sort by.
The result I'd love to have is "Show me all people over 30 and sort them by their 'blue' score"

[Nested documents](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/) always seem to be arrays rather than just a plain hash.

Any ideas?

Comment: This read helped to clarify the situation: http://euphonious-intuition.com/2013/02/managing-relations-in-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 2):

If that is your document structure you don't need a nested document. You can just sort by `scores.blue`.

The point of a nested document **is** in case you have an array of objects.
If your structure was something like this:

```
{
 'name' : 'Sum Guy',
 'age' : 31,
 'scores' : [{
   'name' : 'blue',
   'count' : 5
  }, {
   'name' : 'yellow',
   'count' : 9
  }
 }
 ]
 }
```

Then you would have needed "scores" to be a nested type. When you have an array like that the values of names and counts would be flattened on the top level. Then searching something as "people over 30 where blue is bigger than 5" would not bring back the right results, unless you define it as nested, and then each object in the array is actually a separate document so the context is reserved.

Comment: When trying that, I ended up with: "Parse Failure [No mapping found for [scores.blue] in order to sort on]". I'd be happy to add a mapping, but I'm not quite sure what kind it should be.
    
    "scores":{
      "type":"integer"
    } doesn't seem right since it's a hash with string keys and integer values behind that 'score' key.

Comment: What is the mapping you have there? Cause you don't have to define the mapping yourself, ES generates a dynamic mapping. And if you index a document like you specified, the following search does work: `{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "scores.blue": "asc"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: I have a large mapping, but nothing for that field (yet). I define it myself to be able to not accidentally insert typos and to set indexing to "not_analyzed". I don't really know what kind of mapping I'd need on this field though.

Comment: this is the mapping for the scores: `{
 "your_type" : {
  "properties" : {
   "scores" : {
    "properties" : {
     "blue" : {
      "type" : "long"
     },
     "red" : {
      "type" : "long"
     },
     "yellow" : {
      "type" : "long"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
` . But again, you don't **have** to predefine a mapping. If you index the document the mapping will be dynamically generated by Elasticsearch.

Comment: It's not just blue/red/yellow. It's actually 60+ different values :) Seeing as I have disabled dynamic mapping, I will probably have to figure that one out. Wouldn't adding a second "properties" declaration turn this into a nested field?

Comment: No, a nested type has to be specifically declared, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/ . There's no real problem with having 60+ different values there. Why disable dynamic mapping? It's quite handy and usually there's no reason to disable it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really want to maintain a list of possible values. I just tried dynamic templates, but it doesn't play well with others: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2904 . There has to be a way to set up that mapping. Hmmmm...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35102/discussion-between-rotem-hermon-and-marc-seeger)